# Transaction : Data retrieval needs transaction?

Tags: jpa, transactions

- Wildfly 8.2
- Hibernate 4.3.7
- JPA 2

Hi,

I am using EJB 3 and currently working on a reporting requirement that retrieves data from DB and hands over to highcharts.

Do we really need a transaction when all i do is query the database. I am aware that having no transaction speeds up things but would like to know your inputs in terms of any shortcomings.

Thanks in advance,
Rakesh

**Update:**

Checkout Pro JPA 2 book. It exactly discusses the same thing and it recommends to use @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED) on the session bean methods. It is only logical that the JPA provider has to do a lot less when there is no transaction.

Comment: whenever you are using container managed entitymanger, and EJB, all methods are transactional by default. You should use a container managed entitymanger

Comment: But everything is a transaction (understand and learn about this point), for example even a command line SQL query tool often has auto-commit=yes enabled, so that adhoc SELECT or UPDATE you do is in effect a transaction that is a single statement.  Transactions only slow things down when you start modifying some data, this is a read-only reporting task ?

Comment: *having no transaction speeds up things*: no, that's not true. Transactions are not just for atomicity. They're also for isolation. And using a transaction should actually speed up things, because you'll benefit from the 1st-level cache. If you don't use a transaction, the database will use an implicit transaction for each statement anyway.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Thanks for the comments. Default transaction attribute is Required in case of CMP. Question is about not creating a transaction in the reported case because its ONLY read data.  In that sense, i am talking about method level 'Never' or 'Supports' transaction attributes.

Comment: @DarrylMiles Thanks for the comments. I do understand the transactions and the associated ACID properties. The question is about using transactions when all that is required is ONLY to READ the data. Yes, its purely a reporting functionality.

Comment: @RakeshK.Cherukuri You will be reading using the entityManager find method of some jpql, the thing is container managed entity managers need a transaction to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a bit long to squeeze-in some time to do bit of performance testing. As the initial post clearly states, the question is about using no transaction at EJB level. Found what i was searching for @ http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/j2ee_ejb.shtml. In order to make sure the comments, there in, are relvant with EJB 3.1, did testing and having no transaction (Never or NotSupported) speeds up things to the extent of 30-40%. Seems there is no side effects of it either. Thanks for all your inputs.